# Any client side haml parser?

Tags: javascript, html, haml

I'm looking to render my [haml](http://haml-lang.com/) code in client side using JavaScript. There are nice haml parsers in server side like [Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) or [haml.js](https://github.com/creationix/haml-js) but I don't know any haml parser/decoder in client side.

Update: [Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme) that is pretty much haml now supports client side.

Comment: found [jquery-haml](https://github.com/creationix/jquery-haml) - not really haml but pretty close

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some googling I found the ["client-side-haml-js" github project](https://github.com/uglyog/clientside-haml-js). Looks like it should meet your needs:

> The clientside-haml-js is a compiler written in CoffeeScript that
>   compiles text templates in HAML format into Javascript functions that
>   generate HTML. It has been inspired by the server side haml Javascript
>   project, and has been written to be feature compatible with Ruby
>   server side HAML, supports all major browsers (IE 7+, Firefox 3.6+,
>   Chrome 10+, Safari), have minimal runtime dependencies (only
>   underscore.js, underscore.string and CoffeeScript if using
>   CoffeeScript in your templates).
>
> NOTE: The haml compiler requires a browser with a JSON parser. For
>   browsers like IE7, you need to also include a JSON implementation. See 
>   http://www.json.org/ for more details. A JSON implementation is
>   available at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.

Example from their github page:

```
var fn = haml.compileStringToJs("%h1\n  %div\n    %p\n    %span");
var html = fn();
```

Looks like it also supports a text/haml-template method similar to jquery-templates:

```
<script type="text/haml-template" id="simple">
%h1
  %div
    %p
    %span
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var fn = haml.compileHaml('simple');
    var html = fn();
</script>
```

Comment: But, after looking at their docs, it looks like it compiles from HAML strings into JavaScript that send HTML strings, so not as performant as it could be. For example, instead of compiling to HTML strings it would be much more beneficial to compile to JS API for creating elements, f.e. `var div = document.createElement('div'); div.setAttribute(...); div.appendChild(...)`. Additionally, using DocumentFragment would lead to even more performance, or even better if they make or use a virtual dom library. React is nice because JSX compiles into JS calls that create a virtual dom, which is faster.